# What happens if you initialize a variable but start with 0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=0032;
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

output
26

what actually happened here I tried to search for the answer but couldn't find it

Comment: `0032` is octal (base 8)  see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal  _"...octal-literal is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)..."_

Comment: Interestingly, `0` itself is an octal literal of `int` type.

Comment: Understood clearly thanks for support